# How To Delete a Specific User from Database?

Tags: php, mysql

- Let's say I have an user registered on my website and they now want to delete the account.
- I've a query to do that but every time the user uses this functionality the code deletes all users.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
// starts session
session_start();

// set values
$DB_SERVER = 'localhost';
$DB_USERNAME = 'root';
$DB_PASSWORD = '';
$DB_NAME = 'acoolname';

// creates a new connection to the database
$conn = new mysqli($DB_SERVER, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

// checks connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("ERRO: Falha ao conectar. " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// query to delete the user
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = id";

// logout user
if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
  header("location: logout.php");
}else {
  echo "ERRO: Falha ao conectar. " . $conn->error;
}

// close connection
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE id = 1` might work or better still use a parameterised and bound query `WHERE id = ?`

Comment: *"WHERE id = id"* - Every record in the table will match this condition...

Comment: `DELETE FROM users WHERE id = id`
Well, `id = id` will always be true and this will therefore indeed delete every user. You need to pass in the ID of the user you want to delete after `id =`.

Comment: Relevant [Deleting data from database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67711230/1839439)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`id = id` always returns true, so the query indeed deletes all the users.

The safe way to delete a specific user is to use *prepared statements*, in order to avoid SQL injection.

Something like

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: `$stmt->close();` seems redundant and I don't know why you included it.

Comment: thanks for the help i've used my session variable to delete the current user :)
about the sql injection well this is a school work so i don't i do need to worry about sql injection atm...

Answer (score 1):

Your `WHERE` condition compares for each row whether the `id` for the current row matches the `id`. In other words, the queries compares the field with itself which yields `true`for every row. Therefore every row gets deleted.

You have to replace the second `id` with either a variable that contains the id-value for the current user, or with the id for the current user. The latter is susceptible for SQL injection. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) how to insert parameters into the query, safely.

Comment: i tried something similar as you by importing this `$id = $_SESSION['id'];`  and then `$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = $id";`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
// starts session
session_start();

// set values
$DB_SERVER = 'localhost';
$DB_USERNAME = 'root';
$DB_PASSWORD = '';
$DB_NAME = 'acoolname';

// creates a new connection to the database
$conn = new mysqli($DB_SERVER, $DB_USERNAME, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME);

// checks connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("ERRO: Falha ao conectar. " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// query to delete the user

//Collect the specific user you want to delete from your form
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["user"])) {
    $username = $_POST["user"];

 // Delete user with the specified username
    $sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

// logout user
if ($conn->query($sql) === true) {
  header("location: logout.php");
}else {
  echo "ERRO: Falha ao conectar. " . $conn->error;
}

// close connection
$conn->close();
?>

Missing page of your code is - 
//Collect the specific user you want to delete from your form
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST["user"])) {
    $username = $_POST["user"];
```